# Excel VBA : Showing value in cell from msgbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `MsgBox` and the message includes a count of a range. How do I enter the value used in the `Msgbox`into a cell in the worksheet?

A code sample is below:

```
MsgBox "Todays count is" & " " & Count(Range("g2:g484"))
```

Comment: How does the msgbox receive the numeric value?

Comment: Please share atlease some parts of your code.

Comment: actually i have command button, the code is 'MsgBox "Todays count is" & " " & Count(Range("g2:g484"))' click that cmd , msgbox open and show the numeric value and i want that value into a cell

Answer (score 0):

The number is calculated via a function `Count`. To use the value in a cell, you could assign the count to a variable and then set the value of the cell you want to have the value like so:

```
Dim i As Long

i = Count(Range("G2:G484"))
MsgBox "Todays count is " & i
Worksheets("WS Name").Range("A1").Value = i
```

Amend `WS Name` to the name of your worksheet and `A1` to the cell you want to have the value.

Comment: u mean this on 'Worksheets("WS Name").'  YES